# Clash between C functions imported into a namespace and imported into the global namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

In my code I bring the OpenSSL headers in in a namespace, like this:

```
#include <cstdio>
namespace OpenSSL {
    #include <openssl/ssl.h>
    #include <openssl/err.h>
}
```

But I've just discovered that this seems to cause things to explode if I try to do that when working with Boost ASIO, which has OpenSSL support, but appears to bring the OpenSSL symbols in to the global namespace. Is there anything I can do about this, or do I just have to leave all of the OpenSSL library's symbols in the global namespace?

I did just think of trying a "using namespace OpenSSL" in the offending file after including my header, but that unfortunately causes errors such as:

```
/usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:83:13: error: reference to ‘v3_ext_ctx’ is ambiguous
/usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:71:8: error: candidates are: struct v3_ext_ctx
/usr/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:160:16: error:                 struct OpenSSL::v3_ext_ctx
```

(Note that OpenSSL is a C library, not a C++ library, and thus the original functions are not in any namespace until brought in to a C++ compilation unit. My technique is recommended by Stroustrup in his book *The C++ Programming Language, Special Edition*. From section 9.5, "Advice": "[8] *#include* C headers in namespaces to avoid global names; §8.2.9.1, §9.2.2."

Comment: Could you be elaborate more on those 'exploding things'? A very short sample I was able to create seems to compile fine but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: If in a C++ file you include the above file followed by "#include <boost/asio.hpp>" you'll see the issue. There are a lot of error messages produced, and the exact set varies depending on whether the above header file is included before or after asio. Feel free to e-mail me directly (my address in on my user page) if you have trouble reproducing the problem.

Comment: I assume you mean 8.2.9 (there is no 8.9.2) but it doesn't say that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue seems to be this: OpenSSL's symbols can be brought in only once; a second *#include* of them will have no effect due to the include guards. That means that they can be brought in to only one namespace within a compilation unit.

Thus, if you're going to work with Boost.ASIO in your compilation unit, which requires them to be in the global namespace, you'll have either to bring them in to the global namespace yourself (before you *#include <boost/asio.hpp>* or let *#include <boost/asio.hpp>* do that.

Answer (score 3):

In general this won't work, and isn't supposed to.  Boost.Asio can (and should) expect to be able to reference OpenSSL types as being in the global namespace, e.g. by referring to `::buf_mem_st`, but that fails because you've caused that to be declared as `OpenSSL::buf_mem_st`.

Also, what happens if `<openssl/ssl.h>` includes another header, say `<stddef.h>` (which it does) and that then defines `size_t` as `OpenSSL::size_t`. Any later code that includes `<stddef.h>` will not include it again because it has include guard macros, and now your program can never use `::size_t` because it's incorrectly declared as `OpenSSL::size_t` - for many implementations this will break most of the C++ standard library if included after your openssl includes.  In your case it's possible that `<cstdio>` included `<stddef.h>` anyway, but the same applies to any standard (i.e. non-OpenSSL) header included by the OpenSSL headers, such as `<sys/types.h>`. Your program defines `OpenSSL::pid_t` and `OpenSSL::off_t` and `OpenSSL::timeval` etc.

The only way to fix that problem is to include *every* standard C header before doing your include-in-a-namespace thing, so that if `OpenSSL` tries to include that header again it has already been included correctly, in the global namespace. Even then, other headers referring to OpenSSL (such as Boost.Asio) might break.

Just say no.

Comment: Re, "Also, what happens if <openssl/ssl.h> includes another header...": this is why I _#include <cstdio>_.  ... Wait, it just occurred to me that I probably need the equivalent of _#include <cstdio>_ for stddef.h and the like. Hm. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Yes, you'd need it for *every* header that the openssl libs potentially include (now or in any future version!)

Comment: I think you're a bit overreacting here. There should not be too many problems *as long* as all header files reference their dependencies correctly, and the 'namespaced C include' goes at the end. Of course, that works only as long as no other C++ include references OpenSSL. As boost.asio does that, there's no point even in trying to namespace it since it will hit the global namespace anyway.

Comment: @MichałGórny, _that works only as long as no other C++ include references OpenSSL_ which is precisely the OP's problem You've basically repeated what I said: include all headers before the openssl ones, and it won't work if anything else refers to openssl