# Is there a way to insert a global name into a namespace and make it available only from that namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces

Let's say I have a function with `"C"` linkage in global scope.

```
extern "C" int fun(int);
```

Then if I want to make it visible in a namespace I would do:

```
namespace foo {
   using ::fun;
}
```

But after this I am still able to call it as `::fun(0)` in addition to  `foo::fun(0)`.

So my question is, is there a way to disallow the call from the global namespace for function `fun` and only allow it to be called from `namespace foo`?

Comment: no, that's not possible

Comment: no takebacksies.

Comment: You may try to include c header when you are in namespace.

Comment: everything is possible with [**a little magic**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/097f53bd1d44e061) (see previous link *vs* [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0968ec8e9ed91d87)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the C language does not have namespaces, part of the `extern "C"` specifier indicates that the source name has no namespace.

Thus the following code would invoke the `C` function `foo`:

```
namespace bar
{
    extern "C" void foo();
}

void foo() {}  // note: legal, so no pre-existing ::foo()

void caller() {
    bar::foo();  // calls the C function
}
```

So you could just do

```
namespace bar
{
    extern "C"
    {
        #include "foo.h"
    }
}
```

or if you need to share it with the C code:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
namespace bar
{
    extern "C"
    {
#endif
// .. C-compatible definitions etc
#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: This can be problematic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754581/clash-between-c-functions-imported-into-a-namespace-and-imported-into-the-global?rq=1

Comment: I'm not getting your first example to work with clang++.

Answer (score 11):

The standard clearly establishes that the external C function is declared within a namespace, even if C doesn't know namespaces:

> **7.5/4:** A linkage specification does not establish a scope. A linkage-specification shall occur only in namespace scope.

So instead of declaring the function in the global namespace, you could very well define it directly in your `foo namespace`:

```
// no declaration in global namespace, but... 
namespace foo {
    extern "C" int fun();
}
```

You could then refer to this function only via the namespace:

```
foo::fun();  // yes !
::fun();     // doesn't compile !!!
```

Note that you could even declare the external C function in several namespaces.  They would all refer to the same C function:

```
namespace bar {
    extern "C" int fun();
}
...
foo::fun();  // ok
bar::fun();  // ok - same result as foo::fun();
```

This is guaranteed by the standard :

> **7.5/6:** At most one function with a particular name can have C language linkage. Two declarations for a function with C language
>   linkage with the same function name (ignoring the namespace names that
>   qualify it) that appear in different namespace scopes refer to the
>   same function.

Note that if the extern function was declared in the global namespace in one compilation unit due to some specific constraints, you could still organize that this declaration is not seen in the other compilation units where you would use your local namespace. This is perfectly valid according to the standard statement above.  However, some care would be needed if you play with different visibility in different compilation units !

Answer (score 9):

You can do this since C++11 using a [deleted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions) declaration of an ambiguous function in an [anonymous](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces) [inline namespace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Inline_namespaces):

```
inline namespace { int fun(int) = delete; }
```

Trying to call `::fun(0)` or `fun(0)` will give an error:

```
error: call of overloaded 'fun(int)' is ambiguous
note: candidate: int fun(int)
 extern "C" int fun(int);
                ^~~
note: candidate: int {anonymous}::fun(int) <deleted>
 inline namespace { int fun(int) = delete; }
                        ^~~
```

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e84330267e32dc5).

Comment: Why do you need the anonymous namespace to be inline?

Comment: @conio if the anonymous namespace is not inline, then `::fun(0)` will not give an error, although `fun(0)` will.

Answer (score 4):

You can't prevent any explicit intentional (mis)use here but you *can* hide it in a separate implementation file to make it hard to accidentally use:

In your header, declare the wrapper:

```
namespace foo
{
    int fun(int);
}
```

Then in a single private source file you wrap it up:

```
extern "C" int fun(int);

namespace foo
{
    int fun(int v) { return ::fun(v); }
}
```